# React: Add/Trigger active class to mapped items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I have this component and I map over my array to create a the 10 nav items. How do I add an onClick method to add an active class to the clicked item. Is there a best practice here with Hooks/the newer React way of doing things? Not really looking for a React Router solution here.

Did I miss up by making them `<a>` and `<span>` versus `<ul>` & `<li>`? Does it matter?

```js
import React from "react";

var sections = [
  "arts",
  "business",
  "health",
  "home",
  "movies",
  "opinion",
  "politics",
  "science",
  "sports",
  "technology",
];

export default function Masthead() {
  return (
    <div className="masthead">
      {sections.map((section, idx) => {
        return (
          <a href={section} key={idx}>
            <span>{section}</span>
          </a>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
import React from "react";

var sections = [
  "arts",
  "business",
  "health",
  "home",
  "movies",
  "opinion",
  "politics",
  "science",
  "sports",
  "technology",
];

export default function Masthead() {
 const [cur_section, setCurSection] = React.useState('')

  return (
    <div className="masthead">
      {sections.map((section, idx) => {
        return (
          <a href={"#"+section} key={idx} 
             onClick={() => setCurSection(section)}
             className={section === cur_section ? "active": ""}
           >
            <span>{section}</span>
          </a>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is how you would add an `active` class to an element onClick. The challenger you have with `a` tags of course is that, I assume, they will take you to a different page. So that needs to be addressed in some way.

Notice how I added `{"#"+section}` to href. That's so that we can remain on the current page.

Here is the general idea: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-bush-7n9vf?file=/src/App.js

Comment: whats the tradeoff of just rewriting it as <ul>/<li>. I don't mind doing it. Anything I'm losing? I didn't choose the <a> specifically.

Comment: @Christian I supposed there is no downside to doing that so long as it fits the needs of your app. I recall your React Times site took the user to a new page so you will have to figure that out somehow if you ditch the `a` tags, because li won't link to a different page without some extra JS code.

Comment: yeah, thanks again, I do want the URL to append the new section name "/opinion" or "/sports" but I don't love that it reloads the page. I wasn't able to to implement the React Router issue. I'd have to go back to the beginning and slowly add it back to make sure it doesn't break anything. but yeah, seems like the ul/li won't allow me to add a new page, even with the "# section" part. I may stick with the <a>/<span> just to be able to get it to work how I want. this is a fun project, not work. So I'd rather it work how I wanted it to. thanks!

Comment: and thanks to your "# + section" method, i now don't get the page refresh, but it doesn't refetch with the api. this bit broke "const getCurrentPage = () => {
      const url = new URL(window.location.href);
      const page = url.pathname.split("/").pop();
      return page ? page : "home";
    };"

Comment: You should break the react router trouble you're having into chewable pieces and start posting them here. The community will guide you through it. React router will make your life easier.